# When I try to use grunt serve to view a locally stored web app, the CSS doesn't work. What are the common causes for this?

Tags: css, gruntjs

I think I have installed everything needed and installed it correctly, but I am obviously missing something; or had a misstep somwhere along the line. I am on a Linux and I know for a fact the site works when viewed elsewhere. Here is a screenshot of what I see when I view the site locally: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ElUw.jpg What are the common causes for this?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problems with paths. Open the Chrome development toolbar and check if there's a problem with loading the css files.
You should see them under the "Network" tab after reloading the page.

Comment: Hi anssias, under the Network tab I don't see the css files. I am assuming this means I have a problem with paths, how would I go about fixing those?

Comment: Ok, after I looked around a bit more I found these errors :): GET http://localhost:3000/styles/main.css 404 (Not Found) localhost/:15
GET http://localhost:3000/styles/justified-nav.css 404 (Not Found) localhost/:16
GET http://localhost:3000/styles/custom.css 404 (Not Found) localhost/:17
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js 404 (Not Found) localhost/:20
GET http://localhost:3000/styles/blog.css 404 (Not Found) localhost/:27
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js 404 (Not Found) (index):195

Comment: continue: GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/underscore/underscore.js 404 (Not Found) (index):196
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/backbone/backbone.js 404 (Not Found) (index):197
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/numeral/min/numeral.min.js 404 (Not Found) (index):198
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/affix.js 404 (Not Found) (index):202

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/alert.js 404 (Not Found) (index):203
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/dropdown.js 404 (Not Found) (index):204
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/sass-

Comment: bootstrap/js/tooltip.js 404 (Not Found) (index):205
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/modal.js 404 (Not Found) (index):206
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/transition.js 404 (Not Found) (index):207 GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/button.js 404 (Not Found) (index):208

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/popover.js 404 (Not Found) (index):209
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/carousel.js 404 (Not Found) (index):210
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js 404 (Not Found) (index):211
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/collapse.js 404 (Not Found) (index):212
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/tab.js 404 (Not Found) (index):213
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Does that help narrow down the problem?